# Jquery Add .css to label based on wildcard ID

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following generated code that needs to be modified with jquery

```
<div>
     <input id="priority1" type="radio" name="priority" value="Low" disabled="">
     <label for="priority1">Low</label>
     <input id="priority2" type="radio" name="priority" value="Normal" disabled="">
     <label for="priority2">Normal</label><input id="priority3" type="radio" name="priority" value="High" disabled="">
     <label for="priority3">High</label>
     <input id="priority4" type="radio" name="priority" value="CRITICAL" disabled="">
     <label for="priority4">CRITICAL</label>
</div>
```

I need to add padding to each label (`padding-right: 30px;`)

I have tested with this:

`$j("label[for='priority1']").css("padding-right", "30px");`

It works and it could be argued that I can just repeat it four times for each label; however, I want to use a wildcard like so `$j("label[for='[id^=priority]']").css("padding-right", "30px");`. Unfortunately that did not work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this with jQuery and not CSS?

Comment: @RamenChef we will never know >:) Maybe he wants to only add the padding after a button click or something? Can't really think of a good scenario but there probably is one somewhere.

Comment: The bulk of the tables and forms are generated by an application, including php html js and css files. If i edit them directly the changes would be overwritten next time the application is used to generate the code (i.e. minor changes or a typo etc.) the framework provides for manual code changes by using special 'hook' files. I guess I can use .css directly but im not sure how i would do that without affecting all the other labels on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("label[for^='priority']").css("padding-right", "30px");
```

Seems to work fine here, no need to add id stuff.